# How to know which probability the fitted model gives us

Tags: r, regression, logistic

When I fit a logistic model in r, how do I know which probability the function gives me? I know it is supposed to be the "success probability", but which probability is that?

Answer (score 1):

If your outcome is a 0/1 variable, it gives the probability of 1. If your outcome is a factor variable, it gives the probability of `levels(y)[2]` where `y` is the outcome. If you're confused, change your outcome to be a 0/1 variable where you control which values correspond to 0 and 1. For example, if your outcome `y` had two levels `A` and `B` and you wanted the fitted values to be the probability of `B`, you could run

```
glm((y=="B") ~ X)
```